Fastest way to convert BigInt to Uint8Array?
Situation:
A JSON object that has an array of ~3000 elements. Each element is in format
base64String.base64String.base64String.base64String....

Somewhere around 20-30 base64String separated with ..
These base64String contain lot of information. And values. values are summed together into bigInt. And then the bigInt is converted to byte to be used in hashing and what not.
This entire process needs to be as fast as possible, since this is a small fraction of the complete chain of processing, and everything needs to be fast. The bigInts values are limited to 64bits (Java Long).
I have tested 3 options:
function bigIntToBigEndianBytesLoop(value) {
    const hex = value.toString(16).padStart(8 * 2, '0');
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(8);
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        bytes[i] = parseInt(hex.slice(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
}

function bigIntToBigEndianBytesDataView(value) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(8);
    const view = new DataView(buf);

    view.setBigUint64(0, value);
    return new Uint8Array(buf);
}

function bigIntToUint8ArrayDirect(num) {
    const result = new Uint8Array(8);
    result[7] = Number(num & 0xffn);
    result[6] = Number((num >> 8n) & 0xffn);
    result[5] = Number((num >> 16n) & 0xffn);
    result[4] = Number((num >> 24n) & 0xffn);
    result[3] = Number((num >> 32n) & 0xffn);
    result[2] = Number((num >> 40n) & 0xffn);
    result[1] = Number((num >> 48n) & 0xffn);
    result[0] = Number((num >> 56n) & 0xffn);
    return result;
}

So far it seems tht direct approach is the fastest.
https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/33000/3/bigint-to-bigendian-bytes
Is there any other methods to use?

Could you provide an example of the actual input you have (the one with the base64 (maybe only 2 or 3 slices between . would be enough) so that we can better understand what you are actually doing?

@kaiido Change the description a bit. My mind was elsewhere while writing. BigInts are summed together by values that come from the base64 and then the sum is converted to bigInt.

And so you get a lot of these BigInts, to convert right? Your tests are based on processing a single value at a time. I suspect something like new Uint8Array(new BigInt64Array(arrayOfValues).buffer) might be faster on a batch (though the endianness would make a different result than your versions)

Well i only have 1 big int at a time. I have alot of BigInt <-> Uint8Array and array concatenations. In total prosessing 1 of these elements. takes about 1-2ms, whitch is quite good, but since i have 3000 of them, it adds up.

Note that Number("a", 16) is not the same as parseInt("a", 16). Also, 3 of the 5 benchmarks are as slow as they are because they perform conversions to one or more strings as intermediate values, which is overhead that should be avoided. The biggest surprise is that the DataView approach isn't faster; that's probably due to the allocation cost of the DataView. You'd have to find a way to allocate that only once and then reuse it multiple times; but from your problem description it's not entirely clear whether that'd be feasible.

You could first split the BigInt into two numbers (32 bits), and then continue with those two numbers. This reduces the number of operations on bigints and calls of Number. If the bigint is guaranteed to be in the range of an unsigned 64 bit integer, you can also save on the second & operation. Using >>> you can similarly skip one & operation for each of these two numbers:
// Direct Constructor with Split
function bigIntToUint8ArrayDirectConstructor2(value) {
    const result = new Uint8Array(8);
    const low = Number(value & 0xffffffffn);
    const high = Number(value >> 32n); 
    result[7] = low & 0xff;
    result[6] = (low >>> 8) & 0xff;
    result[5] = (low >>> 16) & 0xff;
    result[4] = low >>> 24;
    result[3] = high & 0xff;
    result[2] = (high >>> 8) & 0xff;
    result[1] = (high >>> 16) & 0xff;
    result[0] = high >>> 24;
    return result;
}

This is what I got:

Benchmark with this variant added as "Direct Constructor with split"
